# Word Problem Re: Student who Misbubbles Scantron

Tags: probability, expectation

[image]

What I've done so far....

We expected he would get $15$ right, so now those $15$ are definitely wrong. So there are 5 he could potentially get right, but he only has a $1/10$ chance of getting each one right. So his expected value is $0.5$ points, which would be $0.025%$ on the exam...this just feels intuitively wrong but I can't put my finger on why. I feel it has something to do with variance in the first step but not sure how to incorporate that. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Not sure the question is clear.  How do you interpret the "wrapping around" language?  Does it mean that, if a student intends to mark $4$ they mark $5$ instead?  Presumably the student never intends to mark any answer greater than $4$, yes?  so, then, what is the point of the "ten options"?

Comment: Assuming my interpretation to be correct, then the expected score on a single question is the probability of accidentally getting it right.  To do that, the true answer must be one of $2,3,4$ (prob $\frac 34$), the student must get it wrong (prob $\frac 14$) and they must intend the answer one less than the true one (prob $\frac 13$) so $\frac 34\times \frac 14\times \frac 13=\frac 1{16}$.  As there are $20$ questions the overall expectation is $\frac {20}{16}=\frac 54$.

Comment: I do believe he means there are 10 options, and if the students means to answer 4 they instead answer 5. If they intend to answer 5 they answer 6, etc. I don't know why else he would include the wrapping around language.

Comment: But that interpretation is inconsistent with "You may assume that when the student is wrong, the chosen answer is randomly chosen among the three incorrect ones."  According to you, there should be nine incorrect ones.  Pretty sure my reading is correct, but if you want to stick with yours the only change is that now the probability that the student guesses one less than the true answer is $\frac 19$ instead of $\frac 13$.  This would change the final result to $\frac 5{12}$.

Comment: Note: the wrapping around language still has meaning under my interpretation.  Were there only four bubbles it would be unclear what the student would do if they intended to answer $4$.  Some rule has to be provided. (with your reading, you need to explain what the student who intends to answer $10$ would do).  I just don't understand why they said "ten options" instead of "five options".

Comment: I just don't think the problem is as simple as that. 75% was just the expected value of his score, it wasn't a sure thing. Technically, for his score to equal the expected value we would have to repeat the process many, many times. I feel this question has more to do with variance and isn't as straight forward as we are calculating.

Comment: Not following.  I assumed the student has a $.75$ chance of getting each question correct.  Of course, you are free to argue that accuracy on this test is highly correlated to ability to complete an ordinary bubble sheet so we can not use the student mean.  But there is nothing in the question to lead us to that concern (and no way to answer the question if the concern is valid).

Comment: Note:  the expectation calculation I gave is linear in $p$, the probability that the student gets an individual question right.  Thus if  we assume the student is drawn at random from the pool it is "safe" to replace $p$ with its mean.  True:  this ceases to be valid if we assume the student is not chosen at random (or if you assume something odd like that the students always get a question right if the answer isn;t $1$ but always get it wrong if it is $1$.)  But under sensible assumptions I don't see a problem here.

Comment: To be clear:  I completely agree with you that the question is vaguely worded.  I do, however, think that sensible assumptions let us get to a reasonable answer.